# Cannot locate Toolbar Configurator in CKEditor 4.5+

Tags: ckeditor

The CKEditor Documentation website states that the Toolbar Configurator "will be available in each official CKEditor installation package starting from CKEditor 4.5."

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_toolbar

I have looked inside the most recent CKBuilder downloads I've made, but I cannot locate the configurator. Is it in 4.5+ as per the documentation site?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the toolbar configurator by opening [`samples/index.html`](http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.0/standard-all/samples/) (and clicking "Toolbar Configurator" option in the menu. Or by navigating straight to [`samples/toolbarconfigurator/index.html`](http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.0/standard-all/samples/toolbarconfigurator/index.html).